# The grand, unified theory of PHP error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

aka, Seeking generic Error Handler (ΟΚ to use commercially)

I doubt that I am the best PHP programmer around, so, although I have my own generic error handler for `set_error_handler()`, I wondered what others do and if there is a "best" (sorry if that sounds subjective - I just want to draw out general approaches (but even the 'best practices' tag has been removed from SO)).

To be objective about it, here's what I think is needed. Please correct me if I am wrong & point me to some good code if you agree.

- I want to capture as much information as possible - without knowing what the error was.
- so, for instance, it makes sense to dump the call stack.
- and `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_SESSION`.
- and I want the call stack & Globals to be pretty-printed
- I want some 'plain-text' layout, not CSS & fancy JS to expand/collapse the information. My users may have to cut/paste into email or even print out & fax.
- I would like to be able to add a header of my own devising, preferably as a parameter, but I can hack the code if need be. The header might include the program version, timestamp, etc (and, in my case, I have an audit track, so I can include the user's last few actions, which led to the crash).
- some users may allow my code to auto-email the report, some may wish to preview it forst & them email it and some may not want me to send email.

Comment: Epic question title, +1.

Comment: No matter what the question, I fave that shiny title.

Comment: As of PHP 7, old-style PHP errors will be treated as exceptions, allowing `try ... catch` etc. That should make PHP error handling a zillion times better (and will hopefully banish that pesky `@` operator once and for all).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I suggest to go the "Exceptions" way.

Throw exceptions when there's a user error, and you can convert php errors into exceptions, like this:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Albeit that this kind of behaviour works best in an OOP kind of environment. If you don't have a single point of entry (like a frontcontroller), you may also catch loose exceptions with this:

```
function myException($exception)
{
    echo "<b>Exception:</b> " , $exception->getMessage();
}

set_exception_handler('myException');
```

Simple debugging with exceptions would go something a bit like this:

```
function parseException($e) {
    $result = 'Exception: "';
    $result .= $e->getMessage();
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    foreach (range(0, 10) as $i) {
        $result .= '" @ ';
        if (!isset($trace[$i])) {
            break;
        }
        if (isset($trace[$i]['class'])) {
            $result .= $trace[$i]['class'];
            $result .= '->';
        }
        $result .= $trace[$i]['function'];
        $result .= '(); ';
        $result .= $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine() . "\n\n";
    }

    return $result;
}
```

From there evaluating globals etc. is a walk in the park. You might look for inspiration to the Symfony Framework Debug Toolbar, which offers many of these requests.

Comment: I like that - I wasn't really thinking of exceptions - more like database problems (but I suppose that they can be exceptions too), or coding errors (default: "unknown switch item") and the like.   Whether we come up with should encompass all of these.

Comment: The nice thing about it is that in your development you may add granular support for different kinds of errors. For example in my ajax enviroment it becomes very easy to propagate any kind of error to the user. It makes my life a lot easier.

Comment: +1 for suggesting single point of entry. You should always have as few entry points as possible.

Comment: Careful with `exception_handlers` though.  Unlike the regular error handler function, your script will terminate at the end of the exception handler function, so all logging, notifications, screen output, etc must be done before that mark.

Comment: I use the same exact things. I like the parseException function. I use dirty var_dump on the stack trace.

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: You're right, doing this with notices will probably give some unwanted situations. You can tweak the set_error_handler function with error masks as the second argument, similar to error_reporting, e.g. set_error_handler('your-function',E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer: ah, I misunderstood your comment (too late to edit). Yes, ideally you should really be able to wrap your code inside a try / catch situation. I would not recommend this for a php4-style (lots of includes, multiple points of entry) project. In that case it's probably better to use a custom error_handler and do some kind of error_log'ing.

Comment: I'm a little late here, but it's interesting that Laravel basically uses this exact approach in their [error handling class](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/error.php).

Answer (score 13):

I can't believe this hasn't been suggested yet.

At my company we just use `Exceptions` with a custom error handler. The error handler will compile a debug message with:

- GET, POST, COOKIES, SESSION, GLOBALS
- A trace
- An error message (either the message in the Exception or the **warning**, yes you should also catch warnings, even **STRICTness** errors).

Then the message is then sent to a **monitoring server**, if that fails, it will try to send us an **email**, it that fails, it will try to **log to a database** (and if that fails it will log to a *file*). If the error is a 'fatal' error in the sense that your output can not be guaranteed, you can choose to throw a 500 header and print a default 'oops' message.

**I would advise you to always automatically report all errors.** The only errors you don't want to know about are errors that are caused by erroneous input by the user. In that case the errors should be presented to the user somehow. I've found that for each exception you can identify whether this is a bug in your system, or an error by a user. For instance: linking to a page, and then removing the page (this will cause a 404). You don't want to know about the 404, but your customer does.

The reason you always want to know about all errors is simple. If your system has a bug you won't know about it unless you either run into yourself, or your customer reports it (which they almost never do).
We used to have a system that was good at hiding all errors and it was super buggy. We started exposing all errors and two years down the road it's a very stable application.

Additionally. There is a trick you can use to catch pesky **`Fatal Errors`**. You can use `register_shutdown_handler` to register a function that will always run after your PHP script has finished. Then you can use `error_get_last` to check for a fatal error. You can then repeat above steps to make the error known to you. This works, I use it all the time.

To round it off. Whatever you choose for error reporting has nothing to do with what the user of your application will see. You can choose to give him an error report, and you could even ask him for feedback at that point. But most of the time there is just a bug in your system so the user can't really do much with it.

Comment: +1 for fallback-safe logging. If I may ask I've been thinking a lot about such kind of system, how did you design the monitoring service? Is it on syslog level, a messaging service, or something written in php?

Comment: It actually just calls a web-service with an HTTP request. So it's a very active monitoring system, it works great.

Comment: +1 sounds good. Any exampel code, or pointers to some, since you can't post your company's code?

Comment: I think the examples on the php.net site should give you enough to start with. Of course I'm not going to post anything regarding the monitoring web-service ;)

Comment: Mawg: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897668/php-monitor-for-all-my-apps-and-sites-errors-logs-etc ?

Comment: +1. Sentry is a great opensource "error monitoring" service: http://getsentry.com

Answer (score 3):

Exposing all your error handling to the end-user is not a good idea.

1) it exposes the internal structure of your code - OK so it should be secure even when a potential attacker has the full source code - but there's no point in making their life any easier.

2) do you really believe that the end-user will conscientiously copy all the information and send it back to you?

3) you are overwhelming the user with lots of information they don't care about.

The way I handle these is to capture as much info as practical serverside (and write it to flat file when an error occurs) then provide a meaningful error message to the user including a simple reference to where I can find the error in the logs. For large scale systems I'd also recommend capturing a fingerprint of the error (e.g. the last 6 digits of the md5 hash of the stack trace) to allow a helpdesk to manage and classify multiple reported incidents of the same underlying fault.

Remember that with PHP all the data is cleared down when the script completes. If you were writing a Java application or a program in C, then you really don't want to be constantly accumulating data - so the only options are to write debug/info entries to a log, then once an error occurs write a stack trace to the log. But with PHP for web pages, I usually keep a log of these in a PHP variable, then write it out to a file **when an error occurs** along with a stack trace (or when the script completes and I've set a flag in the code, e.g. via the session, for analysing how it behaves in non-error scenarios).

How much details you record is up to you - I usually log all fn entry and exit points, and any SQL queries.

e.g.

```
function logit($msg)
{
   global $runlog;
   static $basetime;
   if (!$basetime) $basetime=time();
   $runlog.="+" . time()-$basetime . "s : " . $msg . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you would write execptions to a flat-file rather than the database?

Comment: @jbarlow, of course that's a good great situation to gracefully notify someone via mail (your application would be down), I just find storing in a database table easier to sort through, for example... if a user has reported an issue using a particular page, I store the REQUEST_URI along with the error details and I can perform a query

Comment: My recommendation would be to not give the user this information at all, or optionally give it. Some errors that are extremely fatal (like an unresponsive database) could just be handled in a very generic 'oops' manner, just show a generic error message and send off alerts in the background (email or some other protocol like a webservice).

Comment: Ideally, I would like to just send that info by email, but in some locations the customer has no internet access. In such cases, I expect hime to print & fax it to me.

Comment: @Jaitsu: Error handling must be very VERY robust - writing to a dabase has all sorts of complications which don't exist with flat files - although it would be much preferable to use the logging APIs rather than writing directly to a file. NB you you should never try to write a single flat file directly from PHP as a log file or a database - I'm talking about writing a file for each entry in a log directory.