# PHP monitor for all my apps' and sites' errors, logs, etc

Tags: php, error-handling, monitoring, monitor

### What I'd like

I'd like to have an internal web app in PHP where I can look at all my errors, logs, etc., from all my apps and sites.

Let me paint a picture to explain: I'd like to go to something like monitor.thecompany.com and I will see that there was an error uploading a file on client1.com and that a new user was registered at client2.com.

### Internals

I imagine that I would call a function in my apps and sites (something like `send_to_monitor($type, $title, $description)`), which would send the data to this monitor service. This service would then save the data to the database and later display all the errors and logs for me in a page (e.g. monitor.thecompany.com).

### Questions

1. Is there a solution for this already? I'm a coder so this is not that important for me, but just in case. And if there is, I only want something that can be easily implemented in my apps.
2. What would be the API for the service? How would I do that? RESTful (how would I implement that)? I don't need exact code, just pointers in the right direction.
3. How would I call this service from the client app?
4. What about security? I'm not that worried that someone will read my logs, but if the service is completely open someone could throw new errors in.

Comment: +1 for a good idea. I'd be interested if something similar already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about easy function that would save your logs to one central database?

```
function monitor($type, $title, $description){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://your.error/and_log/handler.php"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "type=".$type."&title=".$title."&desc=".$description."&password=6as5d465as4df987498*/*/*+§§§"); 
    curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch); 
}
```

http://your.error/and_log/handler.php will proccess data and save it

There's nothing easier

Comment: If an attacker found the address of this script. They could pollute your central log with bogus errors (and other bad things like XSS or CSRF). May I suggest adding a password to the handler?

Comment: That handler could have restrictions. For example just few types of logtypes, etc

Comment: Sure you can add password to that

Comment: Yes, security is the only issue I have with this (otherwise great) answer. And this can't be solved with a simple password since it can be sniffed in regular http traffic (don't want to add the https overhead).
Genesis: what kind of other log types are you talking about?

Comment: About the security problem: You can just accept requests from the IP of your server.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that you can use in your PHP to monitor the logs live on the web. Try this :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/webtailx/files/webtailx/

Answer (score 0):

Netuts+ wrote an article on [emailing error reports](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/). You could use a Gmail address so your inbox doesn't get polluted and you have access to special labels, searches, and filters.

Another option is an AJAX powered monitor. Perishable Press [wrote an article on building one for Wordpress](http://perishablepress.com/ajax-error-log-wordpress/) that you could easily adapt for your site.

If you want to push your own messages use [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: None of these work since I 1. don't want emails and 2. is not centralized (i.e. the data is spread across multiple databases).

Comment: Multiple servers won't be a problem. Just pick one database to use (a centralized database server) to host your log database. Have each of the servers for your site connect to this database and add log information.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder, maybe even doing a log web service would be good to capture the log data and insert into a database. That way remote servers could also commit log entries.

Comment: @PhpMyCoder: well the apps can be spread across different hosts, so that can't be a solution

Comment: @duality_ Just because the app is on a different host doesn't mean it can't access an out of host database.

Comment: True, but this does not scale as well as having a central service which then saves the data in a database, since this way you can easily change some aspects of the script (on just one instance).

Comment: You could of course have individual server logs and then grab logs from all servers from a special page (possibly with ajax) if your concerned about scalability. However, I believe this has already been suggested.